# is series (1/n-1/n^2) convergent or divergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I realized none of the series test I ve learnt can determine whether $\Sigma (\frac {1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2})$ is convergent or divergent. is there any note I must consider about this series? I appreciate any help

Comment: $n\ge 2\to \frac 1n-\frac 1{n^2}=\frac 1n(1-\frac 1n)\ge \frac 1{2n}$...

Comment: YES! it did. thank you